# Android: Adding validation to EditText entry

Tags: android, validation, android-intent, android-activity

I want to add validation to the input of my `EditText` so that if a user enters a number outside of 1-12 the application does not move to the next `Activity`, instead I want it to just do nothing and allow the user to re-enter a valid number. I do not know how to do so.

Current code of `EditText` Section:

```
//Setting up next activity to open  via intent
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PracticeTest.class);
//Validation to ensure number is between 1 and 12
if (convertedNumber2 >= 1 && convertedNumber2 <= 12) {
    //pass int value
    intent.putExtra("convertedNumber2", convertedNumber2);

} else {

}
//open activity
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How the user goes to the next activity? By pressing another button? Maybe you can just start with that button disable and enable it once the user has entered a valid number.

Comment: Move `startActivity` to the under `intent.putExtra` (inside the if)?

Comment: move startActivity(intent); inside first if block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //Validation to ensure number is between 1 and 12
        if (convertedNumber2 >= 1 && convertedNumber2 <= 12) {
             //Setting up next activity to open via intent
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, PracticeTest.class);

            //pass int value
            intent.putExtra("convertedNumber2", convertedNumber2);

            //open activity
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opss, wrong value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to display an error message if the user enters a number outside the range?

Comment: I added an extra code sample to show an error message if the value is outside of range.

Comment: I dont think it is working, there is an error i think with the mMYcontext part?

Comment: I fixed it, i needed to put className.this for the context, thanks